# Is it valid to use one sample to estimate the population parameter and to decide whether another observation is in the population?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, inference

I have two groups of samples. Sample A is obtained from population A and sample B is a mixture of unknown origin i.e. some observations of sample B may come from population A and some may not. How can I use sample A to assess whether each observation in sample B belongs to population A or not?

I am thinking of using sample A to estimate population A's parameter (assuming the population is normally distributed) and then calculate the probability of each observation in sample B to be within population A using t-statistic and p-value (two tail test at significance level of 5% and the degree of freedom is the number of samples in sample A - 1). Will such a test to be valid?

I am new to statistics and will appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Confidence intervals.** If you have a sample from (nearly normal) population A,
you can make a 95% confidence interval (CI) for the mean $\mu_A$ of population A. The formula for the CI is
$$\bar X \pm t_c\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where $n, \bar X,$ and $S$ are, respectively the sample size, sample mean and sample standard deviation of the sample, ane where $t_c$ cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

*Example:*  Let's use R statistical software to generate
a normal sample of size $n = 20.$  Pretend these are
your Sample A.

```
set.seed(706)
x = round(rnorm(20, 100, 15), 2); x
 [1]  89.87  90.01  93.57  92.70 122.69  89.29  73.04
 [8] 138.78 112.08 123.58  79.63 105.90 128.22 109.33
[15]  77.97  90.30  99.72 120.50 100.40  94.39
```

Then we compute $\bar X = 101.60$ and $S = 18.02;$
also, $t_c = 2.093$ can be found from a printed table
of t distributions (row 19) or from software.

```
mean(x);  sd(x);  qt(.975, 19)
[1] 101.5985
[1] 18.02439
[1] 2.093024
```

Then the 95% confidence interval for $\mu_A$ is $(93.16, 110.03).$

```
pm = c(-1,1); t.c = qt(.975, 19)
mean(x) + pm*t.c*sd(x)/sqrt(20)
[1]  93.16282 110.03418
```

In R, this CI is included in the `t.test` procedure, so
it can also be found as follows:

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1]  93.16282 110.03418
attr(,"conf.level")    # reminder that this is 95% CI
[1] 0.95
```

Because I generated the sample `x` as a random sample
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma=15),$ it is no
surprise that our CI contains $100.$ Over many such samples, the CI will include $100$ in 95% of the cases.

**Prediction intervals.** However, the 95% CI made from a particular sample, will not necessarily contain a *new* observation from Population A.  If we take five new observations from the same population, let's see what
happens:  Two of the five $(104.16$ and $106.44)$  happen to lie in the CI and the other three do not.

```
set.seed(1234); round(rnorm(5, 100, 15), 2)
[1]  81.89 104.16 116.27  64.81 106.44
```

By contrast, a 95% *prediction interval* (PI) should
on average include 95% of such new observations. The 95% PI is of roughly the same form as the CI, but wider:

$$\bar X \pm t_c\,S\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n}.$$

The quantity under the square-root sign allows for the variability of the original sample of size $n$ and
also for the variability of the new observation.
The 95% PI $(62.94, 104,26)$ can be computed as shown below. Notice that all five of our new observations from
Population A happen to lie within this 95% PI. (Over the long run, about 95% of such new observations from Population A will lie in the PI.)

```
mean(x) + pm*t.c*sd(x)*sqrt(1 + 1/20)
[1]  62.94138 140.25562
```

So if you are want to check a few new observations from
Sample B, from unknown population(s) might be consistent with Population A, you might use a 95% Pi for that purpose.

If you knew more about Population B there might be better ways to discriminate whether observations in Sample B might have come from various sub-populations of Population B. [Perhaps google 'discriminant analysis'.] But just from what you say in your Question, I think using PI's might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, depends. For a single outcome, yes but with the proviso that the answer is only a significant, and not an absolute, one. As the number of outcomes tested increases, it would become increasingly likely that there will be incorrect choices. In the extreme, the answer is no. For example, if we were to generate two populations by Monte Carlo simulation using the identical parameters, and then test outcomes from one population, B, against the observed parameters of A, we would be cutting off observations in both tails of B by calling them unlikely, whereas tail data are likely to have occurred in fact.

One would be better off testing B for containing a mixture distribution.

Comment: You make implicit assumptions about the tests that are not true when appropriate tests are conducted.

Comment: @whuber If the mixture of populations that comprise sample B overlap in their tails, or if the means are close, there is no way to identify which realization belongs to which sub-population in B. In fact, in the limit as the two sub-populations approach each other as to shape, and distribution parameters, there is no way to distinguish them at all. I would approach this problem as an attempt to model B as a mixture distribution with no guarantee of success in absolute terms. What you are talking about I have no idea, if you want to post comments, try being less opaque, please.

Comment: One could, for instance, model $A$ with a specific distribution and use that to create a simultaneous prediction region for future observations.  *Of course* there is no possibility of perfect prediction (or classification of the elements of B), but that's not really the consideration here.  Your negative prognoses in this answer suggest you have altogether neglected such procedures.

Comment: @whuber That is not what I said. Sure I didn't repeat the solution in the other answer and I have not framed anything in absolute terms. No, I haven't excluded the more obvious answer, just furnished an alternative.